# PhoneGap: I need to save text and photo taken with camera to sqlite database

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I'm new to phonegap and trying to develop a phonegap mobile app on visual studio. The app needs to accept input from a textbox and it also needs to allow the user to take a photo. Both the Text and Photo taken needs to be saved in a SQLite database on the mobile device.

I managed to get the text and get it saved on the SQLite database. but I'm having issues with the camera and saving the image on SQLite database.

Please Help!!
Thanks.

//Below is within the also in the index.html page.
//Below is in the body of index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var db;
        function onDeviceReady() {
            db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
            db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }

        function createDB(tx) {
            //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (testtext)');

        }

        function errorCB(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }

        function successCB() {
        }

        function insertDB(tx) {
            var _testtext = $("[name='testtext']").val();
            var sql = 'INSERT INTO DEMO (testtext) VALUES (?)';
            tx.executeSql(sql, [_testtext], sucessQueryDB, errorCB);
        }

        function sucessQueryDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], renderList, errorCB);
        }
```

I have a textbox and two buttons, one for camera and one for save in the body of the same index.html page.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so users can try and help you

Comment: @bolt19, Please see edit above. Thanks!